# azure-devops-node-api - getPersonalAccessTokenHandler(tokenHandler) not working

Tags: node.js, azure-devops

having node v8.15 and Typescript of 3.4.3. Installed the latest version on azure-devops-node-api . imported the module to ts file .

```
let authHandler = azdev.getPersonalAccessTokenHandler(token);
```

giving me error as

```
[SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:
***Failed to load component "50c18491-a471-4da6-8936-11a40cef9265" (HelloWorldWebPart).
Original error: ***Failed to load entry point from component "50c18491-a471-4da6-8936-11a40cef9265" (HelloWorldWebPart).
Original error: Error loading https://component-id.invalid/50c18491-a471-4da6-8936-11a40cef9265_0.0.1
Cannot find module "net"

***INNERERROR:
***Failed to load entry point from component "50c18491-a471-4da6-8936-11a40cef9265" (HelloWorldWebPart).
Original error: Error loading https://component-id.invalid/50c18491-a471-4da6-8936-11a40cef9265_0.0.1
Cannot find module "net"
***CALLSTACK:
Error
at SPLoaderError.SPError [as constructor] (https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_default.js:8390:24)
at new SPLoaderError (https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_default.js:4036:28)
at Function.ErrorBuilder.buildErrorWithVerboseLog (https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_default.js:3789:21)
at Function.ErrorBuilder.buildLoadComponentError (https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_default.js:3697:21)
at https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench-packages/@microsoft_sp-loader/dist/sp-loader-assembly_default.js:6275:47
```

Answer (score 0):

The above issue may raise due to the incorrect reference in the code. 
Other contributors provided a workaround to resolve this issue.

In his case,he tried to call the webpartcontext code and use the below references in the code.

```
1 import IWebPartContext from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base/lib/core/IWebPartContext';    
2 import SPHttpClient from '@microsoft/sp-http/lib/spHttpClient/SPHttpClient';
```

He added the below references by replacing the above code to resolve the issue.

```
1 import { IWebPartContext } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
2 import { SPHttpClient } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
```

You can also try this way to see if it could resolve your issue. For details,please refer to this [link](http://www.ktskumar.com/2018/01/failed-load-component-sharepoint-framework/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: i found that i can use the module azure-devops-node-api when used to simple js file and executed using cmdlt "node <test.js>". But whenever trying to use the module with spfx it giving me issue.